# Java Swing ImageIcon Arrray setIcon displays last image only

Tags: java, arrays, swing, imageicon

I'm having trouble with an ImageIcon array. When I click the JButton on the swing gui the last image of the imageicon is displayed. I want to be able to keep clicking the button and have the image displayed and have it go through all the imageicons in the array.

How can this be accomplished? thank you for your guidance in this matter :)

```
Icon[] myIcons = { 
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image0.png")),
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image1.png")),
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image2.png")),
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image3.png")),
};    

btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnSubmit) {
            for (int i = 0; i < myIcons.length; i++) {
                lblImage.setIcon(myIcons[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Keep track of the last icon you have set, then set the next one when the button is clicked again  (you don't need a loop).

Comment: One call to actionPerformed is one button click.  So you certainly cannot show all the images in one method call.  Keep an index field in your class, and increment it each time the button is clicked (meaning, each time actionPerformed is called).  Obviously you also need to make sure the index is never ≥ the size of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    int curentIndex = -1;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnSubmit) {
            curentIndex = (curentIndex + 1) % myIcons.length;
            lblImage.setIcon(myIcons[curentIndex]);
        }
    }
}
```

use `% myIcons.length` to avoid the index overflow.

Comment: The curRentIndex variable can be a member of the anonymous class being declared just after ```er() {```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I've used the % array.length before I don't know why I didn't think of that. thanks a bunch again :)

Comment: @Scott, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.getSource() == btnSubmit) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myIcons.length; i++) {
      lblImage.setIcon(myIcons[i]);
    }
}
```

Your logic is wrong. Look at this piece of code. see what went wrong. Once you clicked. You are telling the program to loop through each icon after you click the button and not for each click then set the image, so you will get `lblImage.setIcon(myIcons[4]);` at the end of the loop. That's why you are getting the last image.

Instead of putting it through a loop you need to set each Image everytime you click.

```
 int i = 0; 

 btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if (e.getSource() == btnSubmit) {
         lblImage.setIcon(myIcons[i]);
         i++; 
         if(i == myIcons.length-1) i=0;
   }
 }
```